# How to make an auction command

Tags: discord.js

I actually want to make an auction command, it is pretty simple

Me: (prefix)bid 1 mil
Bot: zeyad bid 1 mil
Bot: going once
Some other user: (prefix)bid 2 mil
Bot: user bid 2 mil
Bot: going once
Bot: going twice
Bot: sold to user

So basically i want it to break the command which sends (going once and going twice) when someone else uses the same command. Please help and if i would appreciate if your share code

Comment: No, we aren't going to spoonfeed you. You are expected to research and attempt your goals. This site is to help debug existing code.

Comment: [here you go](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/introduction-to-javascript)